How to Limit Each User to a Fixed Number of Requests in a Locust Stress Test?
I'm currently designing a stress test for a mobile app API using Locust. The goal is to simulate realistic user behavior and stress the system within a one-hour test duration, with a maximum of 20,000 users. However, I need each simulated user to make only 30 requests before stopping.
How can I effectively limit each user to 30 requests within this stress test scenario using Locust? Are there any best practices or better ways to achieve this?
Any insights or suggestions to achieve the desired user behavior would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

There’s no built in way, but have a look at the implementation of locust-plugins --iterations. That only limits the total iteration count but could be modified to be per-user. https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/locust_plugins/init.py#L175
